# Vieta's Formula - Cubic Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, cubics

> Suppose $p(x)$ is a monic cubic polynomial with real coefficients such that $p(3-2i)=0$ and $p(0)=-52$.
>
> Determine $p(x)$ (in expanded form).

I know that the roots are $3-2i$, $3+2i$, and something else, so it is $(x-(3-2i)) \cdot (x-(3+2i))$ then multiplied by the other root. Do I try to plug in $x=0$ and try to find something?

Answer (score 3):

Your intentions are correct. As your polinomial is monic, it will be $$p(x)=[x-(3-2i)][x-(3+2i)](x-\alpha)=(x^2-6x+13)(x-\alpha)$$
I've multiplied $[x-(3-2i)][x-(3+2i)]$ because it will be easier to substitute $x=0$.

Now, plug in $x=0$ and find $\alpha$.